# Dynamic price calculation in laravel

Tags: laravel

**Logic**

```
0~7 KG = fixed price (15000)
8~... = per kilogram add (2000)
```

I want to add `2000` per kilogram to transportation fee when weight is higher than 7kg, how can I do that?

```
if($order->weight <= 7) {
  $transport = 15000;
} else {
  //?
}
```

So if weight is `8kg` transportation will be `17000` if it's `9kg` transportation will be `19000` and so on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$transport=$order->weight>7?(15000+($order->weight-7)*2000):15000;